# Xero webhook issue processing queue

Tags: webhooks, xero-api

We are using a number of webhooks for testing purposes with the DEMO company and this means the webhook queue is full of items.

Is it possible to remove all these items that i am seeing in the webhook queue as i am getting an error about too many requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to remove items from the queue manually. That said, once they've been sent and your script has responded correctly they won't be sent again. As such you should just need to allow your script to receive everything in the queue.

Alternatively you could reset your demo company. This will also reset the webhooks and any data you have entered.